# CakePHP Installation Error, Failed to open stream

Tags: cakephp

I am planning to learn cakePHP. I already installed composer globally, but whenever I run composer self-update && composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_app, I get an error saying:

```
[ErrorException]
copy(/Users/a/.composer/cache/files/cakephp/cakephp/4528680ebd888b7778e5755c957f
c9a26a0d10d1.zip):failed to open stream: Permission denied.
```

To be exact, this error runs after the ff things:

```
- Installing cakephp/plugin-installer(1.1.0): Loading from cache
- Installing aura/intl (3.0.0): Loading from cache
- Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
- Installing zendframework/zend-diactoros (1.7.2): Loading from cache
- Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
- Installing cakephp/chronos (1.1.4): Loading from cache
- Installing cakephp/cakephp (3.6.5): Downloading (100%)
```

I also tried running

```
sudo composer self-update && composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_app
```

but still the error persists. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: That's not a CakePHP problem, but a PHP/OS one, the error message should give you a good hint, PHP doesn't have the required permissions to access the shown the path. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551722/laravel-composer-update-error-permission-denied** | **https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcomposer-php%5D+failed+to+open+stream%3A+Permission+denied**

Answer (score 1):

Change directory to your project directory:

`cd cakePHPproject`

if you know under what user your web server is running then:

`chown -R "userWebserverIsRunning" .` * without " "

above will recursively (-R) change the owner of the files in your current directory (.)

Also set:

```
chmod -R 777 tmp
chmod -R 777 logs
```

PS, If you do not know under what user your webserver is running please run:

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

You can read more on cake's documentation:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html#directory-permissions-on-tmp-and-logs

Have fun!

Comment: It still doesn't work. Currently I am on my project directory, under the user A. I used `<?= `whoami`; ?>` to view the current user. I wrote the ff code.
`chown -R a .`
`chown -R a tmp`
`chown -R a logs`

I also tried 
`chown -R 777 tmp`
`chown -R 777 logs`

Comment: You need to figure out under what user your webserver is running (if apache is usually www-data). If you are not sure please run this command instead of whoami:
`ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}' `

**Please ensure you copy the whole command
then replace a in the command you ran (chown -R a . ) with the output of the command above.

whoami will give you the user you are. You want the files to be able to be written with the user your webserver is running. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: `ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v whoami | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}' `

correct full command

Answer (score 0):

Set the ownership for the cache directory using **`chown` -R** this will recursively change ownership for all files and folders inside cache directory if any

[Reference](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#cache-dir)